# Save updated configurable product attribute to all associated products

Tags: adminhtml, configurable-product, product-attribute

I'm trying to extend Magento to where, when I update a custom attribute for a configurable product, it saves it to the corresponding custom attribute for all of its associated products. I've got an observer that watches the catalog_product_save_after event but I'm not exactly sure where to proceed in order to get it to save it to the associated products. I've looked at a lot of solutions here and other sites that deal with programmatically creating a configurable product and it's assocaited products, but nothing that does what I need. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT: Here's the final code I ended up with:**

```
public function copyAttribute($observer) {
        try {
            // get the event product
            $product = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct();

            // check to see if product is configurable
            if ($product->getData('type_id') === 'configurable') {

                // get associated products
                $associated = $product->getTypeInstance(true)->getUsedProducts(null, $product);

                // create attribute array
                $feedArray = array('feedprice1', 'feedprice2', 'feedprice3');

                // loop through associated products and save configurable products changed value
                foreach ($associated as $associate) {
                    foreach ($feedArray as $feed) {
                        $associate->setData($feed, $product->getData($feed));
                        $associate->getResource()->saveAttribute($associate, $feed);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        // log any errors
        catch (Exception $e) {
            Mage::log(print_r($e->getMessage(), 1), 'null', 'product-attribute-update.log');
        }
    }
```

Comment: Mind that by default Magento displays the information from the configurable product so that you normally do not need to do that.

Comment: Right. What this is for is their GoDataFeed information. The feeds are pulling the associated product values for their custom price attributes instead of the configurable product. So they're having to change the price in a bunch of different places.

Comment: Then I would rather try to fix the GoDataFeed extension which obviously reads the wrong values from the products.

Comment: That's what I suggested. Alas, here we are. :)

Comment: If I understand correctly, than you did not. You try to solve the problem on the Magento side. Although the GoDataFeed extension has to be fixed - it has to get the attributes from the configurable product...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an event product save after  only for configurable product save from admin.

```
    <adminhtml>
            <events>
            <catalog_product_save_after>
                <observers>
                    <stockalert>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>check/observer</class>
                        <method>autoupdatemy</method>
                    </stockalert>
                </observers>
            </catalog_product_save_after>
        </events>
</adminhtml>
```

Then using observer update `field of child products`:i have `update here meta description of child products using parent products meta description`
Code is Here

```
public function autoupdatemy($observer)
{
    try{

    if($observer->getEvent()->getProduct()->getData('type_id')=='configurable'){
        $ConfiProduct=$observer->getEvent()->getProduct();
        $allProducts = $ConfiProduct->getTypeInstance(true)
            ->getUsedProducts(null, $ConfiProduct);
        foreach ($allProducts as $product) {
            $product->setData('meta_title',$ConfiProduct->getData('meta_title'));
            $product->getResource()->saveAttribute($product, 'meta_title');
            Mage::log('myaddr_new_code after-testingnew-'.$product->getData('name').'--'.$product->getId(), null, 'mage32173.log');
        }
    }
    }catch(Excpetion $e){
        Mage::log(print_r($e->getMessage(),1),'null','mage32173.log');
    }

    return;

}
```

**Let me know,if you have any issue**

As your requested Just add below code

**EDIT:**

```
$product->setData('attributecode_1',$ConfiProduct->getData('attributecode_1'));
$product->getResource()->saveAttribute($product, 'attributecode_1');
$product->setData('attributecode_2',$ConfiProduct->getData('attributecode_2'));
$product->getResource()->saveAttribute($product, 'attributecode_2');
$product->setData('attributecode_3',$ConfiProduct->getData('attributecode_3'));
$product->getResource()->saveAttribute($product, 'attributecode_3');
```

Comment: That worked beautifully. Now I just need to extend that so if they update any of the three custom attributes they all get transferred to their corresponding associated products.

Comment: Yep. Thanks a lot Amit. You were a huge help.

Comment: I wish to update the value of the color attribute of the configurable product. Can you tell me the solution